# PHP, Wordpress | $_server 'request_uri' without all slashes. No .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, server, request-uri

my problem: I have a WordPress article into multiple pages.
The URL in this example: http://www.exemple.com/this-is-an-article/2/

About $ _server 'request_uri' i remove the domain. 
Example: this-is-an-article/2

How do I remove the slash before the 2 and replace it with a hyphen?

Best Regards
René

Comment: so article 2's parent article is 'this-is-an-article'?

Comment: Ye. The parent article is 'this-is-an-article'. Clicking paginate link jumps to the page 2 'this-is-an-article/2'